# Install composer and use it with symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I want to use composer with symfony2 my questions are : 
1-Where should I install composer ? inside of symfony folder ? other folder such as /bin ? 
2- where do I configure composer.json ? 
3- should I specify the folder where I'll install a bundle in , in the json file ?

Excuse me,  but the official documentation doesn't offer a detailed explanation ..

Comment: [getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.org/download/) is quite clear - install it both in your dev and prod env, then you just need to run `composer install` from the root folder of the project, location where the `composer.json` file should lie.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll have to ask more stupid questions :
How can I install it in Prod env and dev env ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to install composer globally. From your home dir, execute the following:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Source: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Now you should have `composer` executable from anywhere. You may now go to your Symfony2 dir and run `composer install`.

Comment: Ok, here is my feedback : I can't execute composer from /usr/share/nginx/www/project/
I need to specify the folder where i Have composer.

Comment: What do you mean "cant execute"? What exactly are you trying to execute and what is the exact error?

Comment: Still how does composer find my json file in symfony2 ?

Comment: It's ok for th execution , sorry , but the json file is in a different directory , how can I specify it when running the command update for composer ?

Comment: You have to run `composer install` from a dir that contains a `composer.json` file. If there is no `composer.json` it wont do anything.